# Set theory problem: Prove: for all sets, $A$ and $B$, $A-B=A-(A \cap B).$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Prove: for all sets $A$ and $B$, $~~~A-B=A-(A \cap B).$

**My work:**

Proof.

In order to prove that two sets $X$ and $Y$ are equal, I must prove that $X \subseteq Y$ and $Y \subseteq X$.

Part 1. Prove $[A-B] \subseteq [A-(A \cap B)]$.

Part 2. Prove $[A-(A \cap B)] \subseteq [A-B]$.

**Part 1. Proof**

$\exists x, x \in A - B \Rightarrow x \in A \land x \notin B.$

$\exists y, y \in A-(A \cap B) \Rightarrow y \in A \land y \notin A \cap B.$

This is where I got stuck. I'm not sure if this is a good structure. All I'm sure about is the template. I'm not sure what to do with $y \notin A \cap B$ or even if that's a good starting point.

Comment: Maybe convert $y \notin A\cap B$ to $\neg(y\in A \wedge y\in B) = (y\notin A \vee y \notin B)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Part 1. Prove $[A-B] \subseteq [A-(A \cap B)]$. 
> Part 2. Prove $[A-(A \cap B)] \subseteq [A-B]$.

Part 1. 
$x \in [A - B] \implies (x \in A) \wedge (x \not\in B) \implies $ 
$x\not\in (A \cap B), ~$ [since $(A \cap B) \subseteq B$]. 
Therefore, $(x\in A) \wedge [x \not\in (A \cap B)] \implies x \in [A - (A\cap B)].$

Part 2. 
This is trickier. 
$x \in [A - (A\cap B)] \implies (x \in A) \wedge [x \not\in (A\cap B)].$ 
Suppose that $~x \in B.$ 
Since you also have that $(x \in A)$, this implies that 
$x \in (A \cap B).$  This yields a contradiction. 
Therefore, you can conclude that $~x \not\in B.$ 
Therefore, $~ (x \in A) \wedge (x \not\in B).~$ 
This implies that $x \in (A - B).$

Answer (score 3):

Another method:

$$\begin{align}A-(A \cap B)=A\cap(A\cap B)^c=A\cap (A^c\cup B^c)&=(A\cap A^c)\cup(A\cap B^c)\\
\\&=\emptyset\cup(A\cap B^c)=(A\cap B^c)=A-B\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
x \in A \wedge \neg (x \in B \land x \in A ) \iff x \in A  \land x \not \in B
$$

is a tautology (modus ponendo tollens). Therefore, any element in the set $ A - (A \cap B)$ is in the set $ A - B $ and vice versa.